# Create empty sparse vectors in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have a dataframe DF1 that looks like this:

```
+-------+------+
|user_id|meta  |
+-------+------+
|      1|  null|
|     11|  null|
|     15|  null|
+-------+------+
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- user_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- meta: string (nullable = true)
```

and I have another dataframe DF2 that looks like this

```
+-------+------------------------------------+
|user_id|            Vectorz                 |
+-------+------------------------------------+
|     10|                       (2,[1],[1.0])|
|     12|                       (2,[1],[1.0])|
|     13|                       (2,[0],[1.0])|
|     14|                       (2,[1],[1.0])|
---------------------------------------------
```

Schema is:

```
[user_id: string, Vectorz: vector]
```

I want to inject all the user_ids from DF1 into DF2, but create empty sparse vectors for them since their "meta" column is all NULLs.

So, I want DF2 to finally be:

```
+-------+------------------------------------+
|user_id|            Vectorz                 |
+-------+------------------------------------+
|      1|                            (,[],[])|
|     10|                       (2,[1],[1.0])|
|     11|                            (,[],[])|
|     12|                       (2,[1],[1.0])|
|     13|                       (2,[0],[1.0])|
|     14|                       (2,[1],[1.0])|
|     15|                            (,[],[])|
---------------------------------------------
```

Can somebody please help?

I am new to PySpark. So, sorry if I don't sound informed enough.

Comment: What have you tried? You can try to add `Vectorz` to DF1, drop `meta` then join both dfs together.

Comment: Hi, Can you check my answer? please upvote + accept, if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can go ahead and create empty vectors for all the user_ids when meta is null.
Anyways you need to decide when the meta column is not null.

### Sample COde

1. DF1

```
val spark = sqlContext.sparkSession
    val implicits = sqlContext.sparkSession.implicits
    import implicits._

    val df1 = sqlContext.range(1,4)
      .withColumnRenamed("id", "user_id")
      .withColumn("meta", lit(null).cast(DataTypes.StringType))
    df1.show(false)
    df1.printSchema()

      +-------+----+
      |user_id|meta|
      +-------+----+
      |1      |null|
      |2      |null|
      |3      |null|
      +-------+----+

    root
    |-- user_id: long (nullable = false)
    |-- meta: string (nullable = true)
```

2. DF2

```
    import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vectors
    val staticVector = udf(() => Vectors.sparse(5, Seq((1, 1.0), (3, 7.0))), SQLDataTypes.VectorType)
    val df2 = sqlContext.range(5,8)
      .withColumnRenamed("id", "user_id")
      .withColumn("Vectorz", staticVector())

    df2.show(false)
    df2.printSchema()

    +-------+-------------------+
    |user_id|Vectorz            |
    +-------+-------------------+
    |5      |(5,[1,3],[1.0,7.0])|
    |6      |(5,[1,3],[1.0,7.0])|
    |7      |(5,[1,3],[1.0,7.0])|
    +-------+-------------------+

    root
    |-- user_id: long (nullable = false)
    |-- Vectorz: vector (nullable = true)
```

3. Processed DF

```
  val emptyVector = udf(() => Vectors.sparse(0, Array.empty[Int], Array.empty[Double]), SQLDataTypes.VectorType)

    val processedDF =
      // meta column shouldn't have any value
      // for the safer side adding filter as meta is null
      // need to decide what if meta is not null
      // I'm assigning empty vector to that also
      df1.where(col("meta").isNull)
        .withColumn("Vectorz", when(col("meta").isNull, emptyVector()).otherwise(emptyVector()))
        .drop("meta")
        .unionByName(df2)

    processedDF.show(false)
    processedDF.printSchema()

    +-------+-------------------+
    |user_id|Vectorz            |
    +-------+-------------------+
    |1      |(0,[],[])          |
    |2      |(0,[],[])          |
    |3      |(0,[],[])          |
    |5      |(5,[1,3],[1.0,7.0])|
    |6      |(5,[1,3],[1.0,7.0])|
    |7      |(5,[1,3],[1.0,7.0])|
    +-------+-------------------+

    root
    |-- user_id: long (nullable = false)
    |-- Vectorz: vector (nullable = true)
```

Comment: What do you mean by Array? You have not imported it.


That's when you create an empty sparse vector:


Vectors.sparse(0, Array.empty[Int], Array.empty[Double])